# SwiftyJSON array elements?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, parsing, swifty-json

I have tried finding how to work with SwiftyJSON arrays but nothing seems to work.

My function before using swift was:

```
json.brands.count
json.brands[0].name
json.brands[0].subname
json.brands[0].value

json.brands[1].name
json.brands[1].subname
json.brands[1].value

//Etc
```

Now I’m using:

```
json[“brands”][“name”].exists()
json[“brands”][“name”].string
```

But struggling to insert [0] [1] etc to make it work.

*I’m aware not to use 3rd party content if possible but my JSON api won’t work without a 3rd party. As there is 10 user inputs from a database which has thousands of dynamic entries to the JSON, so I can’t code them all, then there are objects which might be present and if they are present they might contain a value.

I tried the traditional swift json decoder approach but to catch all the errors with a dynamic nested JSON was giving me a headache.*

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for sharing your code. Can you please share your JSON response, so that others will have a better look at it? I think you can simply use a loop to fetch values. Happy coding :)

Comment: I highly recommend you to use Swift's Codable instead of third party JSON libs.

Comment: You see, problem was that I just transitioned to the 3rd party, because I use complex JSON which is a dynamic string as entry, and some objects might not be present and some values of this objects might not be either. The amount of trouble I had catching all the errors and giving responses to each as each errror has to set labels for me, made me switch to SwiftyJSON which makes it so much easier. I’m just missing how to assign the count number of my json using it. I could leave this part in the normal swift jsonDecoder it’s under now, but that will cost me 2 more API calls per request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
json[“brands”][0][“name”].exists()
json[“brands”][0][“name”].string

json[“brands”][1][“name”].exists()
json[“brands”][1][“name”].string
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: String part works, the exists part for some reason doesn’t. But checking for the string alone should do the trick in this case. As I can guard the code with count check before running the script.